# Compilers for STM32F303x

Tags: microcontroller, c, compiler, c++, cortex-m4

Does anyone have any suggestions for C/C++ compiler/debugger for this chip, initially via ST-LINK on a Discovery board? I am currently using IAR EWARM but am not particularly happy with it.

Comment: MDK-5 (Keil)!! IAR EWARM is a compiler for professional programmers! and working with it isn't easy.

Comment: What I particularly hate about "professional" products is that they try and squeeze every last penny out of the company via impenetrable license agreements.

Comment: Just been looking at the Keil stuff - is it free? Can't see a price on it

Comment: No, it's not free. there are also some free compilers like coocox: http://www.coocox.org/CooCox_CoIDE.htm

Comment: I've used Rowley CrossWorks for ARM for many years. It's excellent. http://www.rowley.co.uk/

Comment: Just looked at Keil, and asked them for a quote but I suspect it's going to be more convoluted shit eg "if your cat looks at the screen on alternate Tuesdays we will have to charge you more"

Comment: Is the coocox compiler any good? This is not a hobbyist request.

Comment: Just use a basic GCC install with your favorite editor or IDE and build system.  There's a little learning curve, but then you are completely independent of vendor shenanigans, can recreate a full unrestricted setup on a brand new laptop in an emergency, maintain your code in a VM 30 years from now, fully integrate with your organization's development practices, switch to an entirely different architecture while minimizing changes, etc.

Comment: We stick with IAR - Management Decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Eclipse IDE, with the gcc-arm compiler.  They are both free.

Eclipse is an open source IDE, originally created for Java development.  There's a surprisingly large community of developers who keep adding functionality, such as support for embedded processors!

You can debug via the ST-LINK/V2, and you can use the ST Standard Peripheral Library by simply installing a plugin.

There is some learning curve associating with installing and configuring the tools, but once installed I find them quite helpful and easy to use.  In fact, the more I explore Eclipse, the more helpful stuff I find.  And it's hard to beat "free"!

To give you a head start, I suggest setting them up in this order:

1. Install [gcc-arm](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded).
2. Install [gnu make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), if you don't already have it.  (type `make` into a command line to see if the program already exists)
3. Install the [ST-Link](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM146/CL1984/SC724/SS1677/PF251168?sc=internet/evalboard/product/251168.jsp) utilities.
4. Install [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr1) for C/C++ developers.
5. From within Eclipse, install gdb ("gnu Project Debugger") support. `Help -> Install.. -> C/C++ GDB Hardware Debugging`
6. Install the [GNU ARM Eclipse Plugins](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/plugins-install/), which also integrates the ST Standard Peripheral Library.
7. Finally, install [OpenOCD](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/4-openocd), which is the last piece of the debugging chain.

Enjoy :)